# Modal only showing after the second click

Tags: modal-dialog, vuejs2, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4, vue-component

I'm developing in 1 component = 1 file style in vue2.

I have a Table constructed via a Bootstrap-Vue Table Component, I'm using the provider to pass it an items.

one of the columns contains modify buttons for each row.

these buttons trigger a bootstrap-modal.

I'm using a V-if to initialize the table and its properties.

```
<b-modal  v-if='toShow' id="modalallergy" @hide="resetModal">
      <h4 class="my-1 py-1" slot="modal-header">Allergie {{ modalDetails._id }}</h4>
      <b-container class="bv-example-row">
            <b-row>
                <b-col>
                  identifiant : {{modalDetails.data.content}}
                </b-col>
                <b-col>
                Catégorie : {{modalDetails.data.content}}
                </b-col>
            </b-row>
            </b-container>
    </b-modal>

    <b-modal id="modalallergy-edit" @hide="resetModal">
      <h4 class="my-1 py-1" slot="modal-header">Edition de l'allergie {{ modalDetails._id }}</h4>
      <pre>{{ modalDetails.data}}</pre>
    </b-modal>
```

this is my modal and just above I have my button :

```
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-success" @click.stop="details(row.item,row.index,$event.target)">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
      </button>
```

and below in the `<script>` and `methods` section I have my call :

```
details (item, index, button) {
  this.modalDetails.data = item
  this.modalDetails.index = index
  this.modalDetails._id = item.content._id
  this.$root.$emit('bv::show::modal', 'modalallergy', button)
}
```

the issue is that only the second click on the button will trigger the modal opening. (The properties of the table have not been hydrated yet - at least not from the point of view of the button and modal.)

I also tried using a Boolean and passing the params manually but in that case it doesn't open at all.

Comment: Why are you calling @click.stop?  I wouldn't think you would have to worry about propagation from the component you have described.

Comment: was just trying  things to solve it. it didn't work.

Comment: Could you include in the question what else in the `vue` contents before the `methods` section? it'll help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should have solved the problem, but for future attempts it's my opinion. I had a similar problem. In my case the problem was the v-if used to initialize components inside the modal. I belive if you change the v-if to the h4 and b-container tags will work.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use `v-on:click="details(row.item,row.index,$event.target)"` instead of `@click.stop="details(row.item,row.index,$event.target)"` ? or I'm getting everything horribly wromg :)

Answer (score 1):

Review your code and i am not sure but you can try

```
details (item, index, button) {
  this.modalDetails.data = item
  this.modalDetails.index = index
  this.modalDetails._id = item.content._id
  this.$root.$emit('bv::show::modal', 'modalallergy', button)
  this.$root.$emit('bv::show::modal', 'modalallergy', button)
}
```

Comment: I'm marking as answer because I don't want half the points or all of them to disappear into nothing but it didn't solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a delay to do a little workaround.

```
this.myVar = someThing;
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#mymodal').modal('show');
}, 100);
```