# BootstrapVue modal not showing on first click but works fine on second click

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-vue

I am having an issue using the `b-modal` component i BootstrapVue, This is the click event:

```
responseModal(activity) {
    this.$bvModal.show("responseModal");
    this.response.activity = activity;
}
```

The button has the following code:

```
<button @click="responseModal(activity)" v-if="activity.response_timestamp < time || !activity.my_activity && !activity.type.signup || (activity.response_confirmed || activity.response_declined)" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-hover-info btn-elevate btn-icon" style="align-self:flex-end">
    <span class="we-btn-flex"></span>
    <i class="la la-chevron-right"></i>
</button>
```

When I click the button for the first time, my Vue inspector shows that only one event is fired:

[image]

But modal does not show up until I click again and the inspector shows that a lot of events are fired

[image]

Notice that the first click emits `bv::show::modal` and the next click emits `bv::modal::show`, which again triggers the following commands showed in the inspector. Any suggestions on what I have done wrong?

Comment: Same here! Have you found any solution?

Comment: I honestly forgot what my solution ended up being. I will check my code tonight, and get back to you :-)

Comment: Just check again the official documentation example and everything is working fine. Using it in a v-slot:cell of a bsvue table component, Probably, I just wrong to associate a dynamic ref prop on the modal component. 

Answer (score 4):

i noted the same issue...
i solved simply calling the this.$bvModal.show in a this.$nextTick

Example:

```
this.$nextTick(function () {
    this.$bvModal.show('yourModalId');
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this. VueJS, when in doubt, it's probably a nextTick fix.

Comment: Worked for me too but that would be nice to know why it does not work properly at first...

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was related to the v-if clause. By removing it, the first click worked fine. I got it from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47328857/modal-only-showing-after-the-second-click).